# Calculating assignemnt operators

Tags: math, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Can someone explain to me why the answer to this problem isn't 25,102?

For the following code, suppose the if statement is true 50% of the time.  If so, how many assignment operations occur?  (Don't forget to count the initializations of i and j.  Also remember that i++ and j++ are assignments.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
      temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see how you got 25102, but I think you've not counted the `j` loop properly - it doesn't just add one `j=0` to the total because the whole loop happens multiple times.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize you had to count it like that.